# How does one use Green's function of the operator to get the solution of the arbitrary boundary value problem?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics, greens-function

Assume I've been given an operator $L$ and its Green's function $G(s, s')$. This is the function that solves the following:
$$ L G(s, s') = \delta(s-s'), G(a,s') = G(b, s') = 0 $$
I know how to get a solution of the:
$$ L u = f, u(a) = u(b) = 0 $$
But if the task was:
$$ L u = f , u'(a) + D u(a) = A, u'(b) + C u(b) = B $$
Is there a way to even represent a solution with $G$? Or one would need to solve separately:
$$ L u = 0 , u'(a) + D u(a) = A, u'(b) + C u(b) = B $$
and 
$$ L u = f , u'(a) + D u(a) = 0, u'(b) + C u(b) = 0 $$
Where the last one may be solved invoking new Green's function $N(s, s')$:
$$ L N = 0 , N_s(a, s') + D N(a, s') = 0, N_s(b, s') + C N(b, s') = 0 $$

Comment: Green's function depends on boundary conditions. So you can solve the usual equation with point source and your particular boundary conditions.

Comment: @yuriy-s you mean, having the Gf for one conditions won't help with the others?

Comment: Yes, at least as far as I know. The standard method is finding it for each case of conditions